# Java: Illegal start of expression

Tags: java, path, compiler-errors

I'm just learning Java and wish to use the Path object:

```
Path file = ...;
```

And it's giving me: "Illegal start of expression"

I have the following imports:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;
```

I am running JDK 1.7 platform (JDK 7) according to NetBeans. Have googled to the end of earth and cannot find squat on this error.

I'm assuming *path file = ...;* is some new syntax or feature that my current JDK isn't recognizing???

EDIT |

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.nio.file.*;
import java.nio.file.attribute.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame {

  public MainWindow() 
  {
    initComponents();
  }

  private void cboModelFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) 
  {
    Path file = ...;
  }
}
```

Comment: Relative path is .. actually, 2 dots.

Comment: Show us more than just the beginning of the failing line of code. Show a complete (but short) class where you have this problem.

Comment: Did you literally type `Path file = ...;`, with the unquoted `...`?

Comment: In all the examples I have seen it has been path = ...;

No quotes or nothing...which is partly what confused me...I figured path = ".."; would make more sense but that errors too. Incompatible types or something.

Comment: These two links should help. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html

Answer (score 2):

```
Path file = ...;
```

is not a valid statement, in any version of Java. My guess is that you copied and pasted this from some web site, but the three dots were just meant as an ellipsis meaning "the initialization code must go here".

What do you think these three dots mean?

Comment: I had no idea...I figured the 3 dots was a new language construct introduced in java 7 that I had not been exposed to yet. lol

In any case, I just found some examples:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 1):

The `...` are place holders, these should be replaced with the actual path to the file on your computer. For example if the file exists in `C:\Directory\file.txt`, then the code should be:

```
Path file = "C:\\Directory\\file.txt";
```